# Facebook Timeline - Activity Log - Graph API - FQL Query All Return Data Based Only on Current Value (Major Bug?)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, stream, facebook-fql

We are writing a FQL Query that uses READ_STREAM to see whenever that friend has changed their relationship status (and made that information public) and/or current city. In this case the person’s current relationship_status is set to ‘single.’ We then run a query to see when the user went from being ‘In a Relationship’ to being ‘Single.’

```
SELECT post_id, created_time, source_id, actor_id, target_id, message, description, type FROM stream WHERE source_id = 100003540518168 and (strpos(description, 'relationship') >= 0 or strpos(description, 'Relationship') >= 0 or strpos(description, 'single') >= 0 or strpos(description, 'Single') >= 0) LIMIT 500
```

It returns those instances where the friend has gone from being in a relationship to being single, without returning any information that shows when she entered into that relationship in the first place (the query only looks for words, not words in a particular order, anything with the words relationship and single should appear regardless). Now, let’s change her current relationship_status to ‘In a Relationship’ and run the exact same query.

```
SELECT post_id, created_time, source_id, actor_id, target_id, message, description, type FROM stream WHERE source_id = 100003540518168 and (strpos(description, 'relationship') >= 0 or strpos(description, 'Relationship') >= 0 or strpos(description, 'single') >= 0 or strpos(description, 'Single') >= 0) LIMIT 500
```

It only returns data that shows when she entered into a relationship without mentioning anything of her becoming single even though we clearly know this data exists as from our previous query.

We replicated the same thing using the ‘current city’ variable. If you have listed your current city as Los Angeles, CA, then update your timeline to reflect moving to another city (for example Santa Monica, CA) all history of you having lived in Los Angeles in the first place is gone. However, if you change your 'current city' back to Los Angeles then all of the times you had lived in Los Angeles returns and is now available, without any mention of Santa Monica. This proves it's not specific to relationship status.

This is not just in the API, but also in my own Activity Log on the Facebook website. After changing relationship status to in a relationship:
[image]
After changing relationship status back to single:
[image]

If Timeline is supposed to be a history of your life as you have shared with Facebook, then shouldn’t all changes, moves, be available through the Graph API, FQL query, and listed on the Activity Log (if a user has made the info public)? The data is clearly in the API, however, it is only made available based on your current setting. Is this a bug? Is there a workaround to get all of the data within one call not based solely on a user’s current setting?